# Hybrid - Disk 0 / Disk 1

Tags: boot, disk-utility, diskpart, hybrid-storage

Somehow C and D switched places. I need the boot disk back at Disk 0.

My boot and recovery options have changed as well. C needs to Disk 0 it is the boot and recovery disk.

Comment: On what operating system ? It can be as simple as changing a text file...or much more complex.

Comment: Lenovo Y700 15ISK Touch 64x64 bit

Comment: I believe a possible cause is I was storing a WIM file in D:\ . When I first stored it was 7gb in size 3 days later it was 46gb and the sytem had claimed ownership. It wasn't even a image of this system.

Comment: Where do I look to answer my own question.

Comment: The same as if you where answering a question for someone else.In the answer box below the question, comments and any answers submitted. welcome to superuser

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just ascetics. The disks can be in any order and windows does this automatically based on some algorithm. If you add a drive which was formatted with another system or an older instantiation of your current system; this will affect the disk order.

I have a disk (1 in a group of 4) that when I add it to the cluster it comes up as dynamic but of "foreign origin" that will not take 1st place but it always pushes **all** disk order around in almost random order. This was created on an older instance of Windows system I'm currently running. Maybe even older motherboard.

My guess is that windows makes a hash table of drives which places them in order. If the hash came from a different instance of windows then the order is affected. But I have not found any documentation on it although they do have good document on [MS Disk Management](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/overview-of-disk-management)